# How to show Aptana Studio 3 in the "Open with" list?

Tags: 14.04, programming, ide, aptana-studio

I've downloaded Aptana Studio 3 from their site and installed it successfully. Now it is showing in the Dash search. Problem is that, when I right click on any file (i.e HTML, CSS, PHP etc.), the Apatana Studio is not in the "Open With" list. Even it is not available in the "Other Applications" list.

How can I get Aptana Studio 3 in the "Open With" list?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by editing the file located at `.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` and this file looks like this
according to my settings

```
[Default Applications]
text/x-python=geany.desktop
text/html=geany.desktop

[Added Associations]
text/x-python=geany.desktop;
text/html=geany.desktop;
```

and you can change the opening of the html files using `aptana` editing the `mimeapps.list` as

```
text/html=aptana.desktop
```

if there's `aptana.desktop` in `/usr/share/applications`
for creating `.desktop` file go to

- `/usr/share/applications`
- open any applications with `gedit`

they should look like this

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=System Settings
Icon=preferences-system
Exec=unity-control-center --overview
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Categories=GNOME;GTK;System;
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
Keywords=Preferences;Settings;
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=unity-control-center
```

then change these settings for `aptana studio`
for eg:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Icon=<location of icon>
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Exec=<location of aptana studio executive file>
```

and you don't have to save it in `/usr/share/applications`, you can save it in `.local/share/applications/`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but there is no aptana.desktop in /usr/share/application directory. In that case, what can I do?

Comment: i have edited it